# how to use list.collect or list match to get proper data

Tags: scala

I have a list of string, List("098765432109:rule", "123456789012:*", "123456789012&")
,

I wanna get the first two string in that list and filter out the third one.

When I try list.collecnt, I got Set(FeatureWhitelist(098765432109,All), FeatureWhitelist(123456789012,All)), it seems didn't go into my second regex,

when I try list match, I got "extracting a match result from anything but a charsequence or match is deprecated", 
can anyone help me with that? Or using other methods

```
sealed trait RuleWhitelisting

object RuleWhitelisting {
  case class ByName(name: String) extends RuleWhitelisting
  case object All extends RuleWhitelisting
}

case class Whitelist(accountId: String, ruleWhitelisting: RuleWhitelisting)

lazy val pattrn = "([^:]*):([^:]*)".r
lazy val pattern1 = """(\d*):.*""".r

val res = list.collect {
      case pattern1(accnt) => Whitelist(accnt, All)

      case pattrn(accnt, rule) => Whitelist(accnt, ByName(rule))
    }.toSet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to have:

```
"098765432109:rule" -> Whitelist("098765432109", ByName("rule")) //this doesnt work in your code
"123456789012:*" -> Whitelist("123456789012", All)
```

If so you have wrong `pattern1`. There is `.*` that matches all characters and throws them away. `pattern1` is first rule in your `collect` call and it is used for both examples. You can fix that for two ways:

```scala
//use only one pattern and check if rule name is "*"
val res = list.collect {
      case pattrn(accnt, rule) => Whitelist(accnt, if (rule.trim=="*") All else  ByName(rule))
}.toSet


//or make pattern1 match asterisk symbol instead of anything
lazy val pattern1 = """(\d*):\*""".r
val res = list.collect {
      case pattern1(accnt) => Whitelist(accnt, All)
      case pattrn(accnt, rule) => Whitelist(accnt, ByName(rule))
}.toSet
```

Here is your code with fix:
https://scalafiddle.io/sf/IoI7Whp/1

Comment: Hi Scalway, is there a way that I can log the one when I filter it out?
case _ =>    , is this the correct way, and what should be in there?

Comment: in fiddle above there is third example. Not nicest but works.

Comment: The trick there is to call side effect in if clausure, and this clausure needs to return false. This is not best way of doing things, it's dirty but it is simplest one. Maybe later I will write better solution, but not sure.

Comment: best way probably will be map over list, return `Either[String, Whitelist]` and then filter out   good values. If you will have problem with that write another question please.